# Compatibility issues of version 12 with FilterOptions package

Tags: packages, compatibility, version-12

In version 12, the code

```
If[$VersionNumber >= 9, 
 FilterOptions[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]], 
 Needs["Utilities`FilterOptions`"]]
```

no longer works: the program still throws the error: "Context `` Utilities`FilterOptions `` was not created when `Needs` was evaluated." Does anyone have a fix or workaround?

Comment: I don't see why Needs would be evaluated unless $VersionNumber < 9.

Comment: Have you remove the line  `Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]`? You need to **replace** this line with the `If[…]`.

Comment: @xzczd can you please spell out the changed code you are suggesting?

Comment: You need to **replace** `Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]` with `If[$VersionNumber >= 9, 
 FilterOptions[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]], 
 Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]]`.

Comment: @xzczd So the code would be:`If[$VersionNumber >= 9, 
 FilterOptions[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]], If[$VersionNumber >= 9, FilterOptions[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]], Needs["Utilities`FilterOptions`"]]` ???

Comment: No… I mean you need to 1. Remove the line `Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]` from the package; 2. Add the line `If[$VersionNumber >= 9, FilterOptions[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]], Needs["Utilities\`FilterOptions\`"]]` (or simply `FilterOptions[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]]` if you're always in _v9_ or higher) to the package.